# Is PayPal billing agreement price for last period refunded?

Tags: paypal

I was digging into PayPal docs for Billing Agreement but i cannot find information what happens when user cancels billing agreement before the end of paid period.

Is PayPal refunding money to User base on the rest of payed period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A billing agreement simply means you can process a payment on their behalf at any time.  If they cancel it then you can't run payments, but there is nothing to refund.  It's simply canceling the agreement.